# Oily substance on keyboard beneath silicone keyboard cover

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

When I use cheap silicone keyboard covers, I get a slick, oily residue on the keys *beneath* the cover.

- This has happened multiple times on two different computers with two different covers
- It happens even when I never remove the cover
- The keys and cover were clean to start with
- It's not that they keys *look* oily. There is a tangible substance that I can wipe up with a tissue
- It does not happen when I use a non-silicone TPU cover

Questions:

1. What is this stuff?
2. Can it damage the keyboard, or is it safe to just wipe it off occasionally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's polydimethylsiloxane and dimethylsilanediol. Essentially, it's silicone and silicone breakdown products. Exposure to UV light, acids, bacteria, and even oxygen will slowly breakdown the silicone chains.

Comment: Thank you! As a bonus, do you know whether it can damage the keycaps or the keyboard mechanism, or is it safe to let it collect and wipe it off occasionally?

Comment: Probably not. This is pretty inert stuff. But if the cover was cheaply made, it may have other residues that could harm the keyboard. Personally, I'd switch to a vinyl cover if it's not a cheap, easy to replace keyboard.